# Integration By Parts (Logarithm)

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms

$$\int(2x+3)\ln (x)dx$$

My attempts, 
$$=\int(2x\ln (x)+3\ln (x))dx$$
$$=2\int x\ln (x)dx+3\int \ln(x)dx$$

For $x\ln (x)$, integrate by parts,then I got
$$=x^2\ln (x)-\int (x) dx+3\int \ln(x)dx$$
$$=x^2\ln (x)-\frac{x^2}{2}+3\int \ln(x)dx$$

For $\ln(x)$, integrate by parts, then I got

$$=x^2\ln (x)-\frac{x^2}{2}+3x\ln (x)-3\int 1dx$$
$$=x^2\ln (x)-\frac{x^2}{2}+3x\ln (x)-3x+c$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}x(-x+2(x+3)\ln (x)-6)+c$$

But the given answer in book is $x^2\ln (x)-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{3}{x}+c$. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Have you tried simplifying your answer?

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx}(x^2\ln x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{3}{x})=2x\ln x-\frac{3}{x^2}\neq(2x+3)\ln x$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Bookish answer is wrong:**
$$\left(x^2\ln (x)-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{3}{x}+c\right)'=2x\log x-\frac3{x^2}$$
**And yours:**
$$\left(\frac{1}{2}x(-x+2(x+3)\ln (x)-6)+c\right)'=2x\log x+3\log x=(2x+3)\log x$$

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

$$\int(2x+3)\ln x\ dx=\ln x\int(2x+3)\ dx-\int\left[\frac{d(\ln x)}{dx}\int(2x+3)\ dx\right]dx$$